# Dropdown menu wont stick to table

Tags: php, html, css

I have a CSS related problem, that would look easy, but I have been slamming my head against the wall for the last hour, since the tweaks arround i tried are not applying.

For some odd reason, the select dropdown menu wont stick into the cell, but is placed above the table.See picture below

[image]

The loop code to generate the table is build up as followed: (i didnt bother posting the php cause thats not relevant)

```
echo '<tr class="items">';
echo '<td id="cell11">'.$Date.'</td>';
echo '<td id="cell21">'.$link.'</td>';
echo '<td id="Fright1">'.MakeUserRoleDropdown($StatusId).'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

The CSS is pretty basic:

```
select              { width: 367px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; color: #666; background: white; border: 1px solid #CECECE; padding: 4px;}
.dropdownrole       { width:150px;}
#cell11             { padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; width: 200px; text-align:left;}
#cell21             { padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; width: 200px; text-align:left;}
#Fright1            { padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; width: 200px; text-align:right;}

table.items tr      { height: 32px; background:url(../images/tableRow.png); border-top: 1px solid #CCC; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.items              { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; color: ##797979; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; }
table               { border-spacing:2px;}
```

dropdownrole is in this case te class applied to the dropdown menu.

As you see, the dropdown wont apply to the row and just is put above the table (even in the code it's not even in the cell)  And I cant wrap my head arround why. I made cells already bigger in size (height and width) but no luck.

Did i do something wrong within the CSS?

**EDIT**

Per request of the dropdown function.

```
function MakeUserRoleDropdown($StatusId){
    echo "<select name='StatusId' class='dropdownrole'>";       
    $results = LoadRoles(); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        echo "<option value='".$row['SgroupId']."' ";
                if($StatusId == $row['SgroupId']){
                    echo "selected='selected'"; 
                    };  
        echo ">".$row['SgroupUser']."</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

And here is the output in HTML.

[image: Output in browser as HTML]

Comment: show the MakeUserRoleDropdown php function or at least the html code inside the cell with id="Fright1" ....

Comment: `<td d="Fright1">` -> Is that `d` on your code `id`?

Comment: @ojovirtual that was a typo on my side (its written right in the code)  I corrected it in my post.

Comment: i can not see an error in your code, can you show the html inside a cell with id="Fright1" , there must be a mistake in the html code at some place if you forgot > /> or something or to close a td or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think the problem is, that you call `MakeUserRoleDropdown` which contains `echos`
you proceed to use this method in this string: `echo '<td id="Fright1">'.MakeUserRoleDropdown($StatusId).'</td>';`

Alter your  `MakeUserRoleDropdown` to this:

```
function MakeUserRoleDropdown($StatusId){
    $str  = '';
    $str .= "<select name='StatusId' class='dropdownrole'>";       
    $results = LoadRoles(); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        $str .= "<option value='".$row['SgroupId']."' ";
                if($StatusId == $row['SgroupId']){
                    $str .= "selected='selected'"; 
                    };  
        $str .= ">".$row['SgroupUser']."</option>";
        }
    $str .="</select>";
    return $str;
}
```

And you should be good.

Comment: Indeed, it did fixed it.the double echo breaks it up ... yea makes sense now ... didnt think about that. Thanks

Comment: of course you are right that would  put the select element outside the td id="fright1" because the first echos which are appended are inside the makeuserRoleDropdown <select>....</select><td id="Fright1">undefined</td>